# React component not re-render when a store variable is dispatched in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, rerender

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

import { logedInAction } from '../../redux/userDetails/userDetailsActions';

import Loading from '../Loading/Loading';
import ChatList from './ChatList/ChatList';

const MainWindow = () => {
    const { isLoged } = useSelector( state => state.userDetails );
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const history = useHistory();

    const [ loading , setLoading ] = useState(true);

    useEffect( () => { 
        const dataFetcher = async () => {
            try {
                const res = await fetch( "http://localhost:4000/" , { credentials: 'include' });
                // doing some code and dispatching isLoged variable to true
                setLoading(false);
            } catch(e) { console.log(e); }
        }
        dataFetcher();
    } , [ dispatch , history ] );

    return(
        <>
            {
                loading ? <Loading  /> : 
                isLoged ? <ChatList /> : <div> error</div>
            }
        </>
    );
}

export default MainWindow;
```

When this program starts the variable **lodaing** is true ; so component  is rendered.
After the datafecter is runned variable **lodaing** becomes false and **isLoged** becomes true.

Initially **isLoged** was false ; and I obtained it from redux store. When I dispached it in between into true , it changes its value to true (I saw the value change in react dev tool) . But it is not rerendering it's value.

ie , if **lodaing** is false and **isLoged** is true I should get the component . But unfortunately I'm getting  error  component.This means that **isLoged's** value is not rendered.

**HOW TO SOLVE THIS REDUX RERENDERING ISSUE ?**

Answer (score 0):

This problem might be caused by the delay that React takes to update the local state completely, so you need to use `useEffect` to dispatch your action only when the state `loading` has changed. So:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

import { logedInAction } from '../../redux/userDetails/userDetailsActions';

import Loading from '../Loading/Loading';
import ChatList from './ChatList/ChatList';

const MainWindow = () => {
    const { isLoged } = useSelector( state => state.userDetails );
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const history = useHistory();

    const [ loading , setLoading ] = useState(true);

    useEffect( () => { 
        const dataFetcher = async () => {
            try {
                const res = await fetch( "http://localhost:4000/" , { credentials: 'include' });
                setLoading(false);
            } catch(e) { console.log(e); }
        }
        dataFetcher();
    } , [ dispatch , history ] );

    useEffect( () => { 
       // this "if" guarantee that the local state `loading` and the store state `isLoged` will be false at this point
       if(!loading && !isLoged) {
         // doing some code and dispatching isLoged variable to true
       }
       
    } , [ loading ] );

    return(
        <>
            {
                loading ? <Loading  /> : 
                isLoged ? <ChatList /> : <div> error</div>
            }
        </>
    );
}

export default MainWindow;
```